# Does Commom Crypto library supports below key encapsulation RFC?

Tags: ios, cryptography, commoncrypto

I try to use below RFC algorithm in my app:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5990

Bouncy Castle for c# and java supports it but I am working on iOS. As I know best tools for cryptography in ios is `commoncrypto` library. So the question is that whether this library supports it or not?

I do not find any usefull information on documentation and hope someone here can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any references to it, but it should be *relatively* easy to implement this yourself. You can follow the code of Bouncy and implement using the misnamed `SecKeyEncrypt` with `kSecPaddingNone`. The KDF's used (KDF2 and 3) are rather simple as well.

So although I don't usually recommend implementing crypto functions, this one is relatively safe to implement as the underlying primitives are provided by the platform.